# VFR Reader detect when page did rendered

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf-rendering, vfr-reader

I'm using [vfrReader](https://github.com/vfr/Reader) and I found that `drawLayer:inContext` in `ReaderContentPage.m` called multiple times during rendering. Is it possible to catch page did rendered event?

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to modify the vfrReader source, you can post an event after the `CGContextDrawPDFPage` call in the `drawLayer:inContext:` method. The `CGContextDrawPDFPage` function is synchronous, so the post is guaranteed to be called after the page in question has rendered.

Comment: The problem that drawLayer:inContext called few times and I don't know how many times it will be called.

Comment: why do you need to know when the page has been rendered?

Comment: I want to show "splash screen" and when page loaded show it.

Comment: If it is a single PDF page, then you can do it without using layers (and hence no background tasks). Maybe you do not need all the machinery of vfrReader in this case. Rendering a PDF page is fairly simple. You need to get the current context, and you need to transform PDF page space to your views space. Then you call CGContextDrawPDFPage. You can probably find examples online.

Comment: BTW you can also use a UIWebView and set its location to a PDF url.

Comment: It's not a single page, so in my case vfrReader is very useful. I wan't to show "splash screen" when document is opening.

Comment: Is it possible to know how many times drawLayer:inContext will be called?

Comment: @ChikabuZ - no: it will all depend on some low-level stuff about which portions of a view need to be rendered.

Comment: btw - if all you are doing is drawing a couple of PDF pages into a view, just do it directly. It is not that difficult to code.